# Hyperledger composer error " Cannot create relationship as namespace xyz is not known.

Tags: transactions, namespaces, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

when importing a new example I try to make transaction it throws an error saying that "Cannot create relationship as namespace org.acme.vehicle.auction is not known". 
I previously made changes and played with vehicle auction example and then imported a new one. And this issue is in both chrome and firefoex. Does anyone know what is the solution and why exactly this is happening.

Comment: hi, it sounds like your problem is in your model file(s) - which is why a change of browser wouldn't solve it. The transaction processor script (I assume) for your named transaction  is complaining as the namespace its referring to doesn't exist any longer. So you need to post exactly what you changed (if you based your changes on the original vehicle ie this one -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/carauction-network/models/auction.cto  )

Answer (score 0):

imo, you need to check if the namespace in the `model.cto` file is matching with the `NS='namespace'` in the `script.js` file

Also make sure that you have written the JSdoc annotations `@param` and `@transaction` above every function in the `script.js` file.

Hope this helps you!